# SQL Insertar en una Tabla Histórica la data cuando algún campo es actualizado en la Tabla Original

Tags: sql, script, transact-sql, teradata

Tengo 2 Tablas en SQL: A1 y A2

1. Se insertar todo el contenido de A1 en A2.
2. Si se actualiza algún campo de la Tabla A1 se debe insertar nuevamente todo el contenido de A1 en A2, pero manteniendo el resultado de las data insertada anteriormente.(guardando la historia de los cambios).
3. Se necesita agregar fecha de inicio y de cierre(cuando cambia el valor del dato).

EJEMPLO: INICIALMENTE - Se inserta el contenido de A1 en A2 y se coloca la fecha de inicio V-Date.

```
              TABLA A1                                TABLA A2
+-------------+-------+-------+    +-------------+-------+-------+--------+-----+
| DESCRIPTION |STYLE  | SEATS |    | DESCRIPTION |STYLE  | SEATS | V-DATE |E-DATE
+-------------+-------+-------+    +-------------+-------+-------+--------+-----+
| I10         |Sedan  | 5     |    | I10         |Sedan  | 5     |1/1/2020|      
+-------------+-------+-------+    +-------------+-------+-------+--------+-----+
| I30         |Sedan  | 5     |    | I30         |Sedan  | 5     |1/1/2020|      +-------------+-------+-------+    +-------------+-------+-------+--------+-----+
| Sorento     |SUV    | 6     |    | Sorento     |SUV    | 6     |1/1/2020|      +-------------+-------+-------+    +-------------+-------+-------+--------+-----+
```

Si se da un cambio (update, insert o delete) de algún campo de la Tabla A1 se debe guardar nuevamente todo el contenido de la Tabla A1 en la Tabla A2 diferenciandolo por un ID, pero manteniendo el historial de la data insertada anteriormente en A2.

EJEMPLO: Supongamos que el Campo SEAT de Sorento fue actualizado 30 días después, de 6 a 7.

```
              TABLA A1    
+-------------+-------+-------+          
| DESCRIPTION |STYLE  | SEATS |   
+-------------+-------+-------+    
| I10         |Sedan  | 5     | 
+-------------+-------+-------+ 
| I30         |Sedan  | 5     |
+-------------+-------+-------+    
| Sorento     |SUV    | 7     |
+-------------+-------+-------+   

                   TABLA A2
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
| DESCR |STYLE  | SEATS| V-DATE|E-DATE | ID  |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
| I10   |Sedan  | 5    |1/1/20 |       | 1   |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
| I30   |Sedan  | 5    |1/1/20 |       | 1   |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
|Sorento|SUV    | 6    |1/1/20 |31/1/20| 1   |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
| I10   |Sedan  | 5    |1/1/20 |       | 2   |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
| I30   |Sedan  | 5    |1/1/20 |       | 2   |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
|Sorento|SUV    | 7    |31/1/20|       | 2   |                                
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+-----+
```

1. Se inserta todo el contenido de A1 en A2 con el nuevo cambio.
2. Se actualiza la fecha cuando cambio el registro Anterior (E-Date)
3. Se actualiza la fecha cuando comienza el nuevo cambio (V-Date)
4. Se coloca el ID que diferencia el contenido insertado inicialmente vs el contenido insertado posteriormente.

Y esto prosigue consecutivamente cada vez que se realice algún cambio en la Tabla A1.

ADJUNTO IMAGEN DE EJEMPLO:

[image: Ejemplo]

Query inicial para detectar si cambio algún dato:

```
SELECT T0.*
FROM A1 T0 INNER JOIN  A2 T1
ON T0.DESC = T1.DESC
AND T0.STYLE <> T1.STYLE
AND T0.SEAT <>  T1.SEAT
```

1. Cómo detecto cual fue el campo que cambio?
2. Como actualizo la fecha solo del campo que fue modificado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría crear un trigger.
Son objetos a los que les dices que hacer cuando se realiza un cambio en una tabla.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bkup1 BEFORE INSERT ON A1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO A2(DESCR, STYLE, SEATS, V-DATE,ID) 
    VALUES (NEW.DESCRIPTION, NEW.STYLE ,NEW.SEAT, NOW(),1);
  END;
```

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bkup2 BEFORE UPDATE on A1
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     SET @id = (SELECT id FROM A2 WHERE descr = new.descripcion order by id DESC limit 1)+1
     UPDATE A2 SET E-DATE = NOW() WHERE ID = @id-1;

     INSERT INTO A2(DESCR, STYLE, SEATS, V-DATE,ID)
     VALUES (NEW.DESCRIPTION, NEW.STYLE ,NEW.SEAT, NOW(),@id);
```

Esto es en MariaDB

```
    CREATE [OR REPLACE]
        [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER | role | CURRENT_ROLE }]
        TRIGGER [IF NOT EXISTS] trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
        ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
       [{ FOLLOWS | PRECEDES } other_trigger_name ]
    trigger_stmt
```

En trigger_time defines cuando se debe disparar el trigger, BEFORE o AFTER.

En trigger_event el evento que lo va a activar; INSET, UPDATE o DELETE.

En una misma tabla puedes tener varios triggers y se ejecutarán en el orden que los hayas creado, FOLLOWS y PRECEDES te permiten darle un orden de ejecución a los triggers.

Comment: Buena edición :)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que deseas es llevar un control de versiones de tu documento, pero no esta cumpliendo las `Reglas de Codd` donde tu falla principal es la repetición de datos y falta de dependencia funcional. Pero ignorando eso esta seria una solución:

Primero en tu caso insertar el dato nuevo en A1, después buscar el ultimo dato de A2 que corresponda a lo ingresado ( cambie en A2 el id por `ref`para saber cual es el "padre").

```
 SELECT * FROM A2 WHERE A2.ref = A1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

despues concateno los valores para hacer de ellos una sola cadena y saber cualquier cambio. ( junto la consulta anterior )

```
SELECT * FROM A1
WHERE CONCAT(A1.STYLE,A1.SEAT) 
      !=
      (SELECT CONCAT(A2.STYLE,A2.SEAT)  FROM A2 WHERE A2.ref = A1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Esto me retornara todas los registros en A1 que deben ser copiados en A2 porque existen cambios, si solo lo quieres hacer por un registro en A1 pues aplicas el id.

```
SELECT * FROM A1
WHERE A1.id = :ID AND CONCAT(A1.STYLE,A1.SEAT) 
      !=
      (SELECT CONCAT(A2.STYLE,A2.SEAT)  FROM A2 WHERE A2.ref = A1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Ahora incluso puede hacer `INSERT` automático con.

```
INSERT INTO A2(STYLE,SEAT,ref) 
SELECT A1.STYLE,A1.SEAT, A1.ID FROM A1
 WHERE 
   CONCAT(A1.STYLE,A1.SEAT) != (SELECT CONCAT( SUBA2.STYLE,SUBA2.SEAT) FROM A2 SUBA2 WHERE SUBA2.ref = A1.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Prácticamente es solo copiar el sql anterior después del `INSERT` determinado en el `SELECT` la misma cantidad de campos que el `INSERT`,

> Ademas en el  `FROM A2` renombre por `SUBA2` dado que ya estoy usando el nombre `A2` para el `INSERT`, y usar el mismo nombre de tabla para insertar y seleccionar no es posible ( genera error)

Comment: Es correcto, se desea llevar un control de versiones....Gracias por la explicación. Desde tu punto de vista Cual seria la forma mas indicada para realizar esto, sin ignorar los comentarios y las reglas a seguir....Saludos,!!!